# Special Characters in 14.04 with Alt Right

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout, special-characters

I was using Right <kbd>Alt</kbd> for special characters to my great satisfaction.
Now after upgrading to 14.04 not only it doesn't work but the key is stubbornly launching the HUD.

Worse: The keyboard settings now are changed and less user friendly and i can't change the function for Right <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Furthermore, I find:

*Shortcuts → Typing → Special characters key: disabled*

And that refuses to change whatever I do. The previous version was so easy to use....

To cut a long story short: How to attribute to Right <kbd>Alt</kbd> the function special characters again?

Comment: To the close voters: please hold off on voting until we have determined what kind of "special character" key the OP is referring to; @JPG: When you say you used `Alt` for special characters do you mean you used it as a "modifier" key? I.e.: Did you hold `Alt` down and press another key? Or was it assigned as a "compose" key, i.e.: Did you press it once and then followed up with a specific key sequence to print a special character?